# org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, grpc

Í have just implemented GRPC using lognet.grpc spring boot starter and I am getting following error when starting up the application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' in your configuration.
```

Here is the SpringSecurityConfigurationClass

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring-ADFS-security.xml"})
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private OAuthUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Autowired
  protected void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
  }

  /**
   * @Order annotation is used to advise execution precedence. The highest precedence runs first.
   */
  @Override
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous() //
        .disable() //
        .authorizeRequests() //
        .anyRequest() //
        .authenticated() //
        .and() //
        .httpBasic() //
        .and() //
        .sessionManagement() //
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //
        .and() //
        .csrf() //
        .disable();
  }
}
```

This is the major configuration file which uses adfs-security. Hope it helps.

Comment: can you also share `securityConfiguration` class, because i think that the problem is from there, you are missing some configuration.

Comment: @AndreiLisa added to the post. Please have a look

Comment: ok, just to know, if you add `grpc.security.auth.enabled = false` to your properties file , is it working ?

Comment: i`m going to write  a answer to question , why it is so.

Comment: can you check the answer ? also give me a feedback if it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Just add `grpc.security.auth.enabled = false` in `application.properties`.

Accordin to [Documentation](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter#spring-security-integration) :

- By setting grpc.security.auth.enabled to false, GRPC security can be
  turned-off.
- GRPC security configuration follows the same principals and APIs as
  Spring WEB security configuration, it’s enabled by default if you
  have org.springframework.security:spring-security-config dependency
  in your classpath.

---